# trying to install foobnix using terminal with no success

Tags: command-line, foobar2000

so according to instructions from readme files and foobnix wabpage, i have to type these commands in terminal to install foobnix

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install foobnix
```

and i was doing exactly that and this is what happened:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~foobnix-team/+archive/ubuntu/foobnix-player
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpgq34w_l7/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpgq34w_l7/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 635CDE15 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpgq34w_l7/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 635CDE15: public key "Launchpad PPA for Foobnix Team" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

results of updating, too long didn't read version

```
a lot of stuff linked to foobnix hasn't been downloaded from launchpad because of 404 error 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get install foobnix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package foobnix is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'foobnix' has no installation candidate
```

what to do? i have no idea.

and yes, i tried to find the answer using search engines.

Comment: I don't think your version of ubuntu has that app!

Comment: The [ppa:foobnix-team/foobnix-player](https://launchpad.net/~foobnix-team/+archive/ubuntu/foobnix-player) PPA apparently does not provide packages for Ubuntu versions beyond Vivid